# pdo_odbc driver issue

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I try to running PDO with an ODBC connection.
First at all im running on a 64 bits windows with a 32 bits WAMP installation and finally a 32 bits ODBC driver (does not exist in 64 bits).

Thanks to :

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

I have created a DSN test and I tried odbc_connection :

```
odbc_connect("test", "root" , "root");
```

Connection works and i can perform query.
Then I tried pdo_odbc :

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:test", "root", "root");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

but I get an error ...

```
Connection failed: could not find driver
```

I can't understand why pdo connection failed :'(

PS: pdo_odbc is enabled on phpinfo(); see below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly it's just more stupid... The ODBC driver (nuoDB win ODBC driver) I used was not designed for working with PDO.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to connecting PHP to MSSQL?

Comment: Was not for MSSQL but NuoDB (NewSQL database)

Comment: @user1477388 I know its out of the scope of the original question but to connect MSSQL with PHP use SQLSVR drivers provided by Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 2):

I think your DSN connection string is incorrect. I think it should be something like;

`odbc:Driver={Driver Name}...`

Take a look at some of the examples on the PHP site. It may give you some clues as to what your DSN connection string should be...

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.connection.php